# Creating magic items with random triggers (e.g. burst weapon)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, homebrew, crafting

I'd like to create set of Fascinating Daggers that will have a chance of casting [Hypnotic Pattern](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hypnotic-pattern) or [Hypnotism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hypnotism), something around once every 10 hits (I'd like it to tie it to the attack roll but not stack it with crits so probably on a 10 or 11).

The closest I could find was [Icy Burst](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/icy-burst). However, I'd like to have only the "burst" bit without the [frost](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/frost) enchantment; would it make sense to value it at +1?

Another way to view it would be creating a magic item with a use-activated spell and no space limitation (maybe a rune?). That leads to a 4k or 16k cost but I feel that there must be a heavy discount as it's random. Multiplying with the chance of activating it sounds reasonable although it could be argued that it should be even cheaper. This would give 400/1.6k. So for the lvl2 spell it seems ok to treat it as +1.

Using this formula, for a lvl3 spell and a 4/20 chance of activating, the cost would be close to a +2 (7200).

Thoughts? Is there something similar already?

Comment: What's the purpose of having such a specific weapon? That is, what's your end game when you have it, and what effect do you imagine having? (For example, does an attacker stab someone with the weapon and the weapon leaves the target fascinated and more susceptible to the *suggestion* spell? Or does the weapon, after a stabbing, generate in *pattern* that fascinates all nearby?)

Comment: @HeyICanChan My main motivation is flavour i.e. the daggers' attacks are so elegant that nearby creatures cannot help but stop and admire it (so yes, it should have multiple targets). Overall, I think that having a randomly triggered ability might make a more interesting/unique weapon for the players (like criticals).

Comment: @HeyICanChan The main mechanical benefit is having some crowd control (I agree that perhaps the target creature should be automatically excluded or have a bonus to the save).

Comment: I don't want to answer in comments nor sound condescending, but are you already familiar with the weapon special ability [*spell storing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-storing)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan yeah it's quite similar. the main difference is that with spell storing you can control when the spell is cast but you have to manually recharge it (which would require a wand as the character is a rogue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am looking at [this table of special abilities](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/weapons.html) [and this table](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/magicArmsAndArmor/weaponSpecialAbilities.html) for magical weapons.

I understand your sentiment about not wanting to stack on top of the critical hit mechanic.

Looking through for anything that

- activates through the to hit roll

and

- with a limited chance of activation

They appear all to involve the use of the critical hit mechanism.

But there are a bunch of other abilities with varying methods of activation so you would well be within your discretion to make something different for a set of Fascinating Daggers.

I would recommended the following:

> When the wielder of the Fascinating Dagger rolls his exact chance to
>   hit a target or one greater he may maneuver his dagger in such way to
>   form a magical effect that is the same as a *Hypnotic Pattern* spell.

Looking over the costs of the various special abilities especially between Thundering and Icy Burst I think +2 is a bit on the high side. But it is a close call. I would go with +1 due to the low chance of activating the ability.

Comment: thanks! do you think that increasing the chance (to say 3/20 or 4/20) would make it a solid +2?

Comment: Probably yes. With this kind of thing you will just have to see how it work in actual play.  Remember while it is fight ending effect there is a saving throw involved.